# Retrieve all upper case letters of current culture

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I know that there is `CultureInfo.TextInfo.ToUpper()`, however, is there any way to retrieve a collection of all uppercase letters for a given culture?

Please note that I only want to get all the uppercase letters of the current language's alphabet. E.g. for `en-US` I want to get the list `A,B,C,...Y,Z` (order actually doesn't matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no database built into .NET that keeps track of the letters that appear in the alphabet of a particular language. It would be a very large one. And a controversial one, even a country with a simple alphabet like Dutch has speakers that don't agree whether the Ÿ digraph is in the alphabet or not and at what position it appears.  The former Yugoslavia had two alphabets, wars have been fought over it.  And a changeable one, Swedish added W not long ago, forced to by the World Wide Web.  And a rather unpractical one for a languages like Chinese and Korean.

You do *not* want to have to solve this problem in the general case.

Comment: Thank you, but how does `ToUpper()` work internally if there is no mapping between lowercase->uppercase character?

Comment: That has nothing to do with an alphabet.  It comes up with something, trying to follow the Unicode case mapping rules.  But isn't perfect, "ﬁ".ToUpper() doesn't work right for example.  Details, details.

Comment: Is this also why regular expressions provide only `[A-Z]` and no real "all uppercase letters" character class?

Comment: Hmya, regex was invented in America.  It would probably look a lot different if it were a Chinese invention :)  .NET regex actually does have a class for it, `\p{Lu}`.

Comment: Hmm, if there is no such table, do I have at least access to the underlying used Unicode code table to get the very big list of all uppercase letters? Somehow, the .NET character class has to work too?!

Comment: Char.GetUnicodeCategory() tells you, it still doesn't have anything to do with an alphabet.  Typography and language are weakly related.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actual definition of uppercase, there's a lot of them, just in the Invariant culture, let alone the others, and it varies depending upon your operating system.

This LinqPad query lists 973 (on Win8.1, 873 on Vista, 673 on XP) uppercase characters by my definition, which is the char is invariant to `ToUpperInvariant` and *not* invariant to `ToLowerInvariant`:

```
var UppercaseChars = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 65536)
                    let c = (char)i
                    let u = Char.ToUpperInvariant(c)
                    let l = Char.ToLowerInvariant(c)
                    where c == u && u != l
                    select c;
UppercaseChars.Count().Dump();
String.Join(" ", UppercaseChars).Dump();
```

<sub>[The LinqPad query](http://share.linqpad.net/7v5g6t.linq)</sub>

Obviously you can change this to use `CultureInfo.TextInfo.ToUpper` and `.ToLower` to obtain the list for any culture available.

Note my "definition" of uppercase misses 33 characters (on Win8.1, 135 on Vista, *306* on XP) that are called uppercase by the Unicode Category, but don't have a lowercase alternative (according to `ToLowerInvariant`). However, it also *includes* 69 characters (on Win8.1, 71 on Vista, 42 on XP) that are not defined as UppercaseLetter by the Unicode Category, but still have a lowercase alternative (again according to `ToLowerInvariant`). The latter are *some* of the characters in the Unicode Categories TitlecaseLetter (not in XP), LetterNumber and OtherSymbol. Vista actually includes 4 characters that are in the Unicode Category *LowercaseLetter* (ῃ ῳ ⱥ ⱦ).

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer your question, and your questions in comments: the place to get upper case characters according to the Unicode Category "database" is via `Char.GetUnicodeCategory`. The actual database is not publicly accessible in any other useful way.

For reference you can see the first 255 entries [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs#00d1a0c993b6b079); the rest is loaded [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/charunicodeinfo.cs#e0da3c6199322a6e) and looked up [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/charunicodeinfo.cs#c07c731d275fb0bb).

And remember your definition of upper case may differ from Unicode's, as I mention in my other answer.